# Boot RaspberryPi 3B/3B+/4 from SD card but have everything else on SSD

Tags: boot, bootloader

I have some Raspberries (3B/3B+/4) that I want to boot from SSD, but I also want to attach an HDD to them (the classic SSD for OS and HDD for data)

The thing is that this setup has give me a lot of headaches in the past and nowadays too. When the raspberry boots up, if it finds the SSD first, then everything works correctly. But, if for some reason it finds the HDD first, it won't boot up at all.

As long as the SSD is detected first no problem, but on power outages or reboots it can happen that it won't boot because it found the HDD first which is not bootable.

I couldn't fix that after a lot of tinkering so I was wondering if it could be a viable option to set only the boot partition on the SD card then have the rest of the OS on the SSD and the data in the HDD.

I think some people have managed to do this, but I couldn't find much literature/tutorials on how to do it.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way

create a file, lets call it `sd.txt`, with the following content

```
label: dos
device: /dev/mmcblk0

/dev/mmcblk0p1 : start=        8192, size=      524288, type=c
```

Now, insert your SD card, and run

```
sudo sfdisk /dev/mmcblk0 < sd.txt
```

Now run

```
blkid
```

Look for the line that starts with `/dev/mmcblk0p1` - should look something like this (with different values for the UUID/PARTUUID of course)

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="boot" LABEL="boot" UUID="0123-4567" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="b000b135-01"
```

and take note of the `PARTUUID`

Edit (as root) `/etc/fstab` and find the line that looks like

```
PARTUUID=deadbeef-01  /boot           vfat    defaults,flush    0       2
```

and replace the PARTUUID (`deadbeef-01` in the example) with the PARTUUID you found before (`b000b135-01` in this example) - note, do NOT include any quotes (`"`) i.e. in this example it'll change to

```
PARTUUID=b000b135-01  /boot           vfat    defaults,flush    0       2
```

Now copy the boot partition from the SSD to the SD card

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/mmcblk0p1
```

Reboot and enjoy

Comment: I have a couple questions: 

(1) All these steps should be done with a raspberry that already boots up with an SSD right? 

(2) After this, shouldn't I configure the raspberry to look for the boot partition on the SD card? IIRC some models have a setting you have to turn on/off to enable booting up from USB or SD card

(3) In your first code block, are the numbers after `start` and `size` already always that size or that's your guess? Should I look for the numbers on my specific case? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set your pi 3b/3b+/4b to boot from usb first? You never mentioned that @RabidTunes I would recommend you set your pi 3b/3b+/4b to boot from sd card first if you want to boot from sd card as you stated in your request for assistance